# Regular expression matching multiple patterns

Tags: regex, preg-replace

```
$url = "example-com--folder";
$searchArray = array('/-/','/--/');
$replaceArray = array('.','/');
$url = preg_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $url);
```

The output I want is `example.com/folder` but all I get now is `example.com..folder`

I know this is because I don't have the proper regex pattern, but what would that pattern be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the `'/--/'` and `'/-/'` patterns so that `'/--/'` is checked first, otherwise `'/-/'` will trump `'/--/'`. Don't interpolate the arrays in the call to `preg_replace`.

```
$url = "example-com--folder";
$searchArray = array('/--/', '/-/');
$replaceArray = array('/', '.');
$url = preg_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $url);
```

Alternatives:

- Use multiple calls to `preg_replace` in the order you wish to evaluate the REs. This isn't as objectionable as you might think because `preg_replace` loops over the arrays and handles each RE in turn.
- Use an evaluated replacement

  ```
  $url = "www-example-com--folder";
  $replacements = array('-' => '.', '--' => '/');
  $url = preg_replace('/(--?)/e', '$replacements["$1"]', $url);
  ```
- Use a [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

  ```
  $url = "www-example-com--folder";
  $searchArray = array('/(?<!-)-(?!-)/', '/--/');
  $replaceArray = array('.', '/');
  $url = preg_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $url);
  ```

Comment: This works but it would be great if it were not dependent on the order of the array items.

Comment: You could just use two replacement invocations and get it over with.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestion. For now I will user your first suggestion (change order), and if I need to, I'll go back to doing multiple invocations as meder mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP, right?

You need a quantifier to specify that you want exactly two hyphens in the second pattern. Try:

```
$searchArray = array('/-/','/-{2}/');
```

The curly braces say 'require exactly *n* of the preceding pattern'

Here's a [good reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: I don't even think his syntax is valid, complains because there are no regex delimiters.

Comment: yeah, I think you're right -- I don't have a PHP interpreter at hand at the moment, so didn't bother with whether the function calls work -- I just concentrated on the regex pattern itself. It must work to some degree, tho, as he's getting *some* output...

Comment: Thanks, meder, I added delimiters to my answer. Good catch!

Comment: The curly bracket part works with single replacements but not with multiple replacement as in my code.

Comment: `/-{2}/` is equivalent to `/--/`

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
$url = "example-com--folder";
$searchArray = array('([^-])-([^-])','--');
$replaceArray = array('$1.$2','/');
$url = preg_replace("$searchArray", "$replaceArray", $url);
```

what this says is "match any - that doesn't have a dash before or after and replace that with a ." and "match double -- with /".  obviously, you can extend this to limit the second match to 2 dashes only by adding ([^-]) at the from and back.  as it is, "-----" will become "//", which you may not want.